# Terminating actor System in Akka

Tags: scala, akka

How is it possible to terminate the actor system, once all the sub actors have finished their processing. I have tried to use the following : `system.awaitTermination` and also `system.shutdown`. The result was not the one as expected.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actors don't actually 'finish their processing' - they will still be there in the system, waiting for events to process.

So, to stop it you actually have to explicitly handle the situation where all of your actors have completed their job, for example, by master actor that would expect actors to send it the message when the work is completed, and if all the actors have completed their assignments, shutdown the system.

I would recommend reading a [nice article by Derek Wyatt](http://letitcrash.com/post/30165507578/shutdown-patterns-in-akka-2) (and actually reading his book as well) for standard things like that. There's a [bit more advanced pattern](http://letitcrash.com/post/29773618510/an-akka-2-terminator) by the same author on the same site.

Comment: Please note: as of Akka 2.4, you should use `ActorSystem.terminate()` instead of `ActorSystem.shutdown()`: [Release Notes](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/project/migration-guide-2.3.x-2.4.x.html#Actor_system_shutdown)

Comment: @203 yes, and i have found that you should not do the awaitTermination on the system in the actor, as it is essentially a deadlock :-)

Answer (score -1):

// This is how I did it.

```
helloActor ! PoisonPill.getInstance // send this to all ActorRef in ActorSystem

while (!helloActor.isTerminated) { // check each ActorRef is terminated
  println("sleep")
  Thread.sleep(100)
}
actorSystem.shutdown
```